Download Linux updates now and install only those updates later
I'm using Almalinux 9 and dnf, but RHEL, CentOS, or similar would work the same. Is there a correct way to download updates at one point in time and then install at a later time? I have dev/test servers and prod servers. I would like for the dev/test servers and prod servers to download updates at the same time. That's no problem. I schedule dnf upgrade --downloadonly /my/cached/updates -y and I have all the RPM files in a single directory, and it's the same RPMs on dev/test and prod. Now let's say I want my dev/test servers to install upgrades at the same time that they download them, but I want my prod servers to wait a full week before install. I don't ever want to install anything on my prod system that hasn't been installed and tested in dev/test first. So I don't want any new updates in prod that may have been released during the week after I upgraded dev/test but before I upgrade prod.
Should I simply run dnf install /my/cached/updates/*.rpm -y on prod a week later or is there a better way of going about all of this?

Why not just skip the step and set a cron job to install the updates at the time that that you want?


Set up a repo on your master server:


dnf install createrepo_c
createrepo_c /path/to/RPMs
Serve it via nginx/apache/vsftpd whatever


Point your slave servers to this repo (you can check existing repos in /etc/yum.repos.d/ - yeah, it's still yum for compatibility)
Run dnf --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=master update on your slave servers

AI should have probably given the same answer in under 30 seconds.

Option N2: may or may not work, probably it should:

Distribute RPMs however you want (rsync/scp/etc or even serve them via Samba/NFS/etc)
Run

cd /directory/with/RPMs
rpm -Uvh *rpm

The first method is a lot more preferable.

I get enough half-baked answers from AI, not to trust it when I want a solid answer. Trusting AI is like saying 2+2=5 is close enough.

Both ChatGPT and ClaudeAI have been quite good recently. Like really good.
